# How many constructors does the class have?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I'm preparing for an upcoming C++ exam and came across this question about classes and constructors:

> #### How many constructors does the class Fraction have?"
>
> ```
> class Fraction {
> //...
> public:
>    Fraction(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1);
> //...
> };
> ```

I thought it's only one, but they suggested there are three:

```
Fraction();
Fraction(n);
Fraction(n, d);
```

Or in other words:
**Is a function with default values an overloaded function?**

Comment: There are actually three call variants that can be used, but theres only one constructor. That's either a trick question or asked unclearly. Should have been **"How many constructor call candidates does the class Fraction have?"** Bad question otherwise, sue them if you fail the exam because of that :-P.

Comment: As for your question, _overloaded_ for what actually?

Comment: There are also implicitly declared copy and move constructors...

Comment: It all boils down to whether **they** gave you those 3 constructor invocations as "proof" that there are 3 constructors, if that's the case **they** are likely inadequate. They likely have the answer **3** which counts implicitly generated constructors as well, but without the clarification or knowledge that's the case, so they threw that confusing nonsense at you to simulate adequacy, hoping they will get away with it and you won't come asking here on SO :)

Comment: Look at the generated machine code and you'll see those three calls all call the same routine - and the "default" arguments are present (pushed or put in registers, as appropriate) at the call site.  So "they" are wrong.

Answer (score 55):

There is only one constructor corresponding to the posted declaration, not three overloads.

The calls

```
Fraction();
Fraction(n);
```

are equivalent to:

```
Fraction(0, 1);
Fraction(n, 1);
```

One more way to convince yourself that there is only one constructor corresponding to the declaration is that you only need to define one constructor, not three.

The section of the C++11 standard on default arguments has this:

> **8.3.6 Default arguments**
>
> 1 If an *initializer-clause* is specified in a *parameter-declaration* this *initializer-clause* is used as a default argument. Default arguments will be used in calls where trailing arguments are missing.
>
> 2 [ *Example:* the declaration
>
> ```
> void point(int = 3, int = 4);
> ```
>
> declares a function that can be called with zero, one, or two arguments of\ type `int`. It can be called in any of these ways:
>
> ```
> point(1,2); point(1); point();
> ```
>
> The last two calls are equivalent to `point(1,4)` and `point(3,4)`, respectively. *—end example* ]

Now the main question.

> **How many constructors does the class Fraction have?**

If the person that framed the question wants to include the move constructor and the copy constructor, which are implicitly generated by the compiler unless explicitly deleted, in the set of constructors, then **the answer is three**. In that case, the question is a trick question.

Comment: Compiler generated copy and move constructors count or not? Answer would still be 3 if so. Looks like a _trick question_ for me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I am talking about the constructor corresponding to the declaration, not others.

Comment: Sure, I know. But may be the question was written by some bad ass.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I see what you are saying. Agree that the question can be improved a bit :)

Comment: Well, you cannot deny that taken the snippets litterally there are actually 3 constructor definitions (unrelated to these 3 call variants of the defined constructor available as shown in the sample). It's actually a trick question, I'd bet my ass.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, you can bet your ass all you want :) I'm not not betting my ass on questions framed by tricksters.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Are the default ones implicitly defined only if you default them explicitly or if you actually use them? In this case, there are _potentially_ three constructor definitions, but it mostly depends on the rest of the code.

Comment: When I was in education and on a C++ course the answer would have been 3 to make sure we remembered about the default and copy constructors that get automatically generated.  I was in education between early 2001 to 2006.  If that question is from an older exam paper, it will be about copy and default constructors to make sure students remember they will be there even if not shown in code.

Comment: @TafT, the default constructor will not be generated by the compiler in this particular case since the declared constructor also works as the default constructor. In pre-C++11 days, the answer to that question would be 2. This must be a newer question.

Comment: @TafT - I agree with you - and thus disagree that this question is a trick question (if this is the reason - as discussed elsewhere if the "reason" is that you can _call_ the declared destructor three different ways - then its a _bad_ question).

Comment: The question still has no clear answer - since parts of the class are omitted, it isn't clear whether there are any members which inhibit generation of the implicit constructors.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, that posted code seems to hint that there is only one explicitly declared constructor.

Comment: @RSahu But there could still be members that have no copy or move constructor of their own.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, in a class called `Fraction`, that is highly improbable.

Answer (score 27):

> **Is a function with default values an overloaded function?**

No. Overloads look like

```
Fraction();
Fraction(int numerator);
Fraction(int numerator, int denominator);
```

and have each their own implementation (definition), while a function with default parameters has a single implementation.

---

> I thought it's only one, but they suggested there are 3: ...
>
> **"How many constructors does the class Fraction have?"**

## It's a trick question, designed to fool you showing the available call variants for a *single constructor* declaration.

The **definite** answer for the given code snippet is **3** (in words **three**).

There's one specialized constructor (which serves three variants of calling), and the compiler generates a copy and move constructor automatically if you don't `delete` them, or provide a custom implementation:

```
Fraction(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1); // (1)
// Redundant, just for demonstration:
Fraction(const Fraction& rhs) = default; // (2)
Fraction(Fraction&& rhs) = default; // (3)
```

---

So for such exam, if you will answer

> The class has one constructor

That's wrong anyways. If you will answer

> The class has three constructors *(as you wrote that is the accepted answer)*

you'll need to explain in depth, why you think so (as explained above).
In any oral exam I'd ask you to backup why exactly, so I'd do in an apprentice test.

Answer (score 18):

The answer to your question is relative to these three follow-up questions:

1. Before C++ 11, C++ 11, or C++14 and beyond?
2. Do the implicitly defined constructors count?
3. What are the members? The presence of a non-copyable member will delete the implicit copy constructor.

The explicit definition is only one constructor; the compiler will insert a three-argument call regardless of whether the call explicitly supplies 0, 1, or 2 arguments.

In pre-'11 there are no move constructors, in '11 there are two implicit constructor definitions, `Fraction(const Fraction &) noexcept` and `Fraction(Fraction &&) noexcept`, check the accessible [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor), in '14 the rules of when there is an implicitly defined move constructor change.

The question you got is unfortunately innocently looking but quite technical; I hope your class does not insist on oversimplifying C++, it is the worst way to learn it.

Answer (score 5):

You have only one declaration of a constructor.
On the other side:

> When two or more different declarations are specified for a single name in the same scope, that name is said to be overloaded

Because of that, I'd not use the term *overloaded* here.

Answer (score -4):

This kind of function definition defines a single function but 2 additional calling syntaxes.  The subtle difference becomes apparent when taking function pointers or matching a template function argument to overloaded functions: in that case you only have a function with full argument list as the available overloaded type.

Now the tricky thing is that we are talking about a constructor here, and a constructor does not engage in the same kind of overloading resolution as an ordinary function and is, for all purposes, not accessible other than syntactically.  In particular, this definition *does* count separately as a default constructor.  It also counts separately as a converting constructor from int and can be used as ((Fraction)3).

So for all practical purposes, it creates three different *syntactic* entities in the constructor category.  And as opposed to ordinary functions, there is no functional context where overload resolution would expose the difference between three actual function signatures and three merely syntactical calling conventions.

This is not a good question for a written test.  This is really something for an oral exam since there are so many subtleties involved that the difference between a formally correct answer (if any) and a formally wrong answer is not likely to correlate well with actual knowledge and skill, and the reasoning behind any answer is more important than the answer itself.

Comment: _"and a constructor does not engage in the same kind of overloading resolution as an ordinary function ..."_ Huh what?

Comment: No "additional syntaxes" are created. This has nothing to do with syntax.

Answer (score -5):

Because it depends on the arguments you pass:

```
Fraction() --> Fraction(0,1)
Fraction(n)---> Fraction(n,1)
Fraction(n,m)
```

So it gives 3 constructors. No overloading is taking place here.

Comment: _"So, it gives 3 constructors"_ No. That's only one constructor, that provides 3 different options for calling.. _"No overloading is taking place here"_ sounds contradictorily, and I don't see what your answer adds benefically over what already has been stated.